# How to use python copy from or copy_expert

Tags: python

I’m trying to use the python copy from or copy expert method- not sure which one is better to copy a huge csv file from a directory to my targeted table in postgres database.My data is large  >28 GB , hence why i need a method that is fast and efficient.

Will appreciate an example of python code of how to do it.

I trier copy from didnt work